# Creating Multiple objects using a script attached to multiple objects C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A bit confusing I know and I know I have posted this script recently however essentially I am trying to spawn the objects this code is looking for whenever a bool is active , and since it's attached to multiple objects it should just create a clone of each designated object bu it will only create one object and it is random which object it creates each time.
This is Using C# in unity

Thanks for your time and patience 
Ryan.

```
public void HQModelSpawn()
{
    HighQualityModel = false;

    Transform[] HQTransforms = this.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();



    foreach (Transform t in HQTransforms)
    {
        if (t.gameObject.CompareTag("HighQualityModel"))

        {
            HQMesh = t.gameObject;


            Instantiate(t.gameObject, CurrentPosition, Currentrotation);

            transform.position = CurrentPosition;
            transform.rotation = Currentrotation;



            Debug.Log("Found " + t);

            break;


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Are you looking for singleton?

Comment: You'll probably want to remove that `break` statement: it aborts the `foreach` loop after the first object is instantiated.

Comment: Just tried that didn't make any diffrense

Comment: What do you exactly want? Have a script, which if attached to any kind of GO, it'll keep spawning clones of it, as long as a bool somewhere is true? As the code above is different: it grabs the one and only transform your GO most probably has, and duplicates that in one copy (if it has the tag "HighQualityModel") when HQModelSpawn() is called.

Comment: Is that `CompareTag` call meant to check that `HighQualityModel` boolean property of your script? If so, that's not what it's doing. Game object tags and script properties are two different things. I'm not very familiar with Unity, but if I remember correctly you'll need to use the `GetComponent` method to access scripts that are attached to a game object, so you can inspect their properties.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Nope, that's there to determine the GO's "type" so to speak and clone only those sharing that tag (hopefully... otherwise there are serious problems with the coding up there :)

Comment: @Mark: I understand that, but the OP may not. Just asking him to make sure. :)

Comment: To explain better i am trying to create every object with the tag " Highquality" model , but each object this script is attached to has to spawn the tagged object that is within its own hierarchy , so any parent or child object.